# What is the difference between sfForm and baseForm in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I want to make a custom Form but I don't know which class to extend: `sfForm` or `BaseForm` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look ...

```
BaseFormDoctrine ---extends---> BaseForm  ---extends---> sfForm
```

So in your case you want to create custom Form and use Doctrine facilities (like: save(), ...etc) you should extends

> BaseFormDoctrine

And add

> parent::setup();  to your code to enable Doctrine facilities .

Comment: Well, if you want to use Doctrine facilities in a Form you should better extends the dedicated Object form (like `lib/form/doctrine/MyTableForm.class.php`) instead of create a new one ... Otherwise your save() function will save nothing in DB.

Comment: About use MyTableForm.class.php instead of create a new one ... there no command line to create only one form i want ,the existing command build all forms ... what if i want only one form !!!

Comment: Why do you need a command line to create a Form ? (and I think it's off topic)

Comment: that is the issue in most cases i want only one form to use .... So, i make a custom form instead of build all forms (unwanted)

Answer (score 1):

Good question, I usually extends `sfForm` for all my new form but I should use `BaseForm`, regarding [to the doc](http://www.symfony-project.org/tutorial/1_4/en/whats-new#chapter_a2fae23c9403b0e9ec99806fccf6b53e_sub_baseform):

> Every new symfony 1.3/1.4 project includes a `BaseForm` class that you
>   can use to extend the Form component or add project-specific
>   functionality.
>
> The forms generated by `sfDoctrinePlugin` and
>   `sfPropelPlugin` automatically extend this class.
>
> If you create
>   additional form classes they should now extend `BaseForm` rather than
>   `sfForm`.

Answer (score 0):

Base form is where you put your project specific form related code. Use that cause it extends(through some other classes) from sfForm(as far as i know).